# Ruby: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Sorry for my poor English. I got the error like below.

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:69:in `block in show'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:67:in `each'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:67:in `each_with_index'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:67:in `show'
```

Here is the code in 'tasks_controller.rb':

```
@teammates_form = Array.new(@teammates.size-1){Hash.new}
@teammates.each_with_index do |t, idx|
  if t.id != current_user.id
    @teammates_form[idx]['id'] = t.id  # <--- line 69
    @teammates_form[idx]['name'] = t.name
    @teammates_form[idx]['t_id'] = @task.id
  end
end
```

But if I change codes like:

```
@teammates_form[0]['id'] = t.id
@teammates_form[0]['name'] = t.name
@teammates_form[0]['t_id'] = @task.id
```

It works... I don't know why I can't use index in array.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with that array being created and that you are accessing the indices' incorrectly. Have you tried just printing out what it says? Like print idx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#                                          ⇓⇓  ? WHY?
@teammates_form = Array.new(@teammates.size-1){Hash.new}
```

You yield this error on the last iteration on `@teammates`, since `@teammates_form` is 1 element shorter.

Comment: Thank you for finding error!  I did -1 to exclude some data. Now it works fine! Thank you again and sorry for my stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see which time through the loop the error happens using something like Pry?

I suspect that actually it is on the last time that the error is happening. On the first line of your code you create an array of hashes using `Array.new(@teammates.size-1){Hash.new}`. This means that if `@teammates` contains 3 items, your new array will only contain 2 hashes (ie `[{}, {}]`). This in turn means that for the final team mate, `@teammates_form[idx]` will be nil. Try using `Array.new(@teammates.size){Hash.new}` instead and see if that helps.